Is it possible to change the proxy periodically?
The issue I'm facing is related to using paid proxies that require authentication with a username and password. When I attempt to automate proxy switching with ChromeDriver, a popup appears asking for these credentials, and I can't seem to bypass it using Python. My goal is to connect to the proxies automatically and rotate them at set intervals, but I'm stuck at this step because I can't get past the popup authentication.
I tried using ChromeDriver to automate proxy connections, and I expected it to handle the authentication popup that asks for the username and password automatically. I also implemented proxy rotation in Python, assuming it would switch proxies seamlessly after a set time period. However, the popup for proxy authentication keeps appearing, and I haven't been able to bypass it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think you want to solve popup problem when authenticate proxy.
Please check this link.
how to set proxy with authentication in selenium chromedriver python?

I haven't tried this, I'll check it out
